# First order differential equation with time-varying parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have:
$\dot{\sigma}(t) = -\gamma \sigma(t)$

where $\gamma$ is a constant, the solution is given by:

$\sigma(t) = \sigma(0) e^{-\gamma t}$

Now what if I have the differential equation:
$\dot{\sigma}(t) = -\gamma x(t) \sigma(t)$

Then is the solution given by:

$\sigma(t) = \sigma(0) e^{-\gamma x(t) t}$

Or...?

Comment: Think about it: if $\sigma(t)=\sigma(0)e^{-\gamma x(t)t}$, then $\sigma^\prime(t)=?$. Do you get $-\gamma x(t) \sigma(t)$? No! What could you put in the exponent to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1):

Say I do something like this: 
$$
\frac{\dot{\sigma}(t)}{\sigma(t)} = -\gamma x(t).
$$
can you integrate both sides? 
What do you get on the left side? 
What do you get on the right side?

(In case it's confusing, the answer will have something like $\int x(t) dt$ in it.)